# Can I say that this sequence admits a non-zero limit?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, limits

Fix integers $b,k\geq2$ and non-zero rationals $a_1,\dotsc,a_k$. I have a sequence $(n_1^s,\dotsc,n_k^s)$ of integers such that:

1. $\max(n_1^s,\dotsc,n_k^s) = n_1^s$ for every $s$.
2. Every subsum of $y_s = y(n_1^s,\dotsc,n_k^s) = a_1 b^{n_1^s} + \dotsc + a_k b^{n_k^s}$ is non-zero.

I would very much like to show that this is enough to guarantee that
$$\liminf_{s\to\infty} \frac{y_s}{b^{n_1^s}}$$
is finite and non-zero.

---

- Finiteness is more or less a given, because by hypothesis 1 we know that $0 < b^{n_i^s-n_1^s} \leq 1$ for every $i$ and every $s$.
- It could be helpful to consider the equivalent problem with $a_1,\dotsc,a_k$ non-zero *integers* (to see that this is equivalent, just multiply $\frac{y_s}{b^{n_1^s}}$ by a common denominator of the rational $a_i$).

**Note:** This is *not* homework and this result could very well be false. If that is the case, a counterexample would be appreciated.

Comment: The [tag:number-theory] tag is there because this question arose while trying to solve a problem in number theory. If you can think of better tags or a more descriptive title, please feel free to edit them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** that if $c_j=\liminf_{s\to\infty} b^{n_j^s - n_1^s}$ isn't zero, then there is an $R_j>0$ such that
$$ c_j=b^{n_j^r - n_1^r} $$
for every $r\geq R_j$. Indeed, if $c_j\neq0$ then
$$ c_j^{-1} = \limsup_{s\to\infty} b^{n_1^s-n_j^s} $$
but $b^{n_1^s-n_j^s}$ is a sequence of integers, hence any of its subsequences eventually agrees with its limit, if it exists (observe that either $\sup_{t\geq s} A_s$ is either $\infty$ or $\max_{t\geq s} A_s$ if $A_s$ is a sequence of integers).

Now, clearly $\frac{y_s}{b^{n_1^s}} = a_1 + a_2 b^{n_2^s - n_1^s} + \dotsc + a_k b^{n_k^s - n_1^s}$. Since $\liminf$ is superadditive, we have
$$
C = \liminf_{s\to\infty} \frac{y_s}{b^{n_1^s}}
\geq a_1 + \sum_{j=2}^k \liminf_{s\to\infty} a_j b^{n_j^s - n_1^s}
= \sum_{j=1}^k a_j c_j
$$
Up to reordering we may assume that there is a $1 \leq h \leq k$ such that $c_j\neq0$ for $j\leq h$ and $c_j=0$ for $h>k$. If $R = \max_{1\leq j\leq h}{R_j}$, then
$$
C = a_1 + \sum_{j=2}^k a_j b^{n_j^R - n_1^R}
$$
therefore hypothesis 2 implies that $n_1^R C$ is non-zero.